# Accelerate python program using python-C-API and POXIS threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, c++11, python-c-api

I wrote some program in python, which runs steps similar to, but more complicate than following steps:

STEP 1: Given a **BATCH** of lists with same length, each element of one list represents the number of states it may have, I need to DFS all the possible states(represented by 0,1,2...) of one list and get them in one list. e.g. input `[[1,2,1], [2,2,2]]`, the output of this step should be `[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]`

STEP 2: Calculate some value related to the output of STEP 1, and return a dict with the form: 
`{"0,0,0": 0.1,
 "0,1,0":0.2,
 "0,0,1":0.56,
 "0,1,0":0.68,
 "0,1,1":0.3242,
 "1,0,0":0.8987,
 "1,0,1":0.214,
 "1,1,0":0.2,
 "1,1,1":0.9}`

STEP 3: In this step I need to process a **BATCH** of lists. While processing, I need to lookup(just read operation) the dict returned by STEP 2 very frequently, and generate one tuple for each list in the batch.

I found my program really slow in STEP 1 and STEP 3. STEP 2 can only be down in python by some reason. What's more, lists in batch are independent from each other, they only share the same dict in STEP 3. So I want to use multi threading to process these lists in parallel.

Since python has GIL, `threading` module doesn't work.
Then I tried `multiprocessing`, even slower(I guess it is because of context switching and data transferring).
Then I used c++11 to write a .so module containing functions receiving `PyObject` and returning `PyObject`. I used POXIS threads, but it always raised `SegmentFault` error as long as I use more than one thread. I carefully read the document of python-C-API, and found GIL is still needed,
 refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads). So this doesn't help at all.
Then I used `Cython` by declaring types of all variables by `cdef`, it did accelerate but not that much.

I'm losing myself in this problem. Can anyone help me? I'll be really really grateful.

Comment: reads like a classic map reduce problem and you're hurting to reinvent the map reduce pipeline rather than writing your mapper and reducer in an existing framework.

Comment: Step 1: I don't really see how your output comes from your input, but `itertools` defines good implementations for this kind of thing. Step 3: The GIL is needed where you're using Python threads or C++ threads - you won't win here.

Comment: One further thought - I think a dict is the wrong structure and you should store your step 2 data in a 3D numpy array. The lookup in step 3 will probably be much quicker.